# Uploadify demo page not working in Firefox 29.0.1 and 13.0.0.214

Tags: jquery, flash, uploadify

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/ - this page dont work with the lastest versions of Firefox and Adobe flash player width error: Some files were not added to the queue:
The file "NAME" is empty.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe made security changes in 13.0.0.214 that restrict upload operations. There is no easy workaround unfortunately. A bug has been filed: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3759971